# How to use variable names of jdbc preprocessor in jsr223 preprocessor?

Tags: jdbc, jmeter, preprocessor, jsr223, variable-names

1. set variable names on jdbc preprocessor.

```
    variable names : aa,bb
```

2. excute query

```
    select aa, bb from table;
```

3. try to get the variable names on jsr223 preprocessor

```
   log.info(vars.get("aa"));
```

but this via aa is null

how to use variable names?

Answer (score 0):

Looking into [JDBC Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request) Sampler documentation:

> If the Variable Names list is provided, then for each row returned by a Select statement, the variables are set up with the value of the corresponding column (if a variable name is provided), and the count of rows is also set up. For example, if the Select statement returns 2 rows of 3 columns, and the variable list is A,,C, then the following variables will be set up:

> ```
> A_#=2 (number of rows)
> A_1=column 1, row 1
> A_2=column 1, row 2
> C_#=2 (number of rows)
> C_1=column 3, row 1
> C_2=column 3, row 2
> ```

So it will be:

- `vars.get('aa_1')` - for first row of the `aa` column
- `vars.get('aa_2')` - for second row of the `aa` column
- `vars.get('bb_1')` - for first row of the `bb` column
- etc.

More information: [Debugging JDBC Sampler Results in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/debugging-jdbc-sampler-results-jmeter)